# Can't Change Resolution?

Tags: resolution

I just got Ubuntu and I can only get two resolutions
800x600
1024x768

My monitor is 1600x900

When I try to use Xrandr I get xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Please Help me I don't want to have to go back to windows :P

Comment: Am I realizing that Linux is not very reliable?